# Cannot implement try/catch/finally when variable is final

Tags: java, lucene, compiler-errors

I have a problem.

I am using a variable which has to be final because I am using it in a anonymous inner class.

```
try { 
    final IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(index.getDirectory(),true);

    searcher.search(query, new HitCollector() {
                public void collect(int doc, float score) {
                    try {
                        resultWorker.add(new ProcessDocument(searcher.doc(doc)));
                    } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
                        log.error("Corrupt index found during search", e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("Error during search", e);
                    }
                }
            });
} catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
    log.error("Corrupt index found during search", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Error during search", e);
} finally {
    if(searcher != null) 
        searcher.close();
}
```

Problem is that I get a compiler error saying `searcher cannot be resolved`

And if I move the searcher up like so:

```
final IndexSearcher searcher;
try {
    searcher = new IndexSearcher(index.getDirectory(),true);
```

Then I get compile error saying `searcher may not be initialized`.

How can I fix this?

PS: I cannot use Lombok @Cleanup because the field has to be final for the anonymous inner class to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try { 
    // if new IndexSearcher throws, searcher will not be initialized, and doesn't need a close. The catch below takes care of reporting the error.
    final IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(index.getDirectory(),true);
    try {
        searcher.search(query, new HitCollector() {
                public void collect(int doc, float score) {
                    try {
                        resultWorker.add(new ProcessDocument(searcher.doc(doc)));
                    } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
                        log.error("Corrupt index found during search", e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("Error during search", e);
                    }
                }
            });
    } finally {
        searcher.close();
    }
} catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
    log.error("Corrupt index found during search", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Error during search", e);
} finally {
}
```

Comment: So here you are not closing the searcher in the catch? Because the new IndexSearcher throws CorruptIndex and IOException. Shouldn't saercher ble closed then?

Comment: No, I close it in the inner finally which will be executed always and only if `new IndexSearcher` succeeds. If the `new` throws, searcher will never be initialized, and doesn't need to be closed.

Comment: Yeah, generally you don't want to have `catch` and `finally` sharing the same `try` block.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit ugly, but I think this will do the trick;

```
IndexSearcher searcher = null; 
try { 
    searcher = new IndexSearcher(index.getDirectory(), true);
    final IndexSearcher finalSearcher = searcher;
```

and replace `searcher` with `finalSearcher` in the anonymous inner class.

Comment: Not sure if I like this hack :-)

Comment: You don't have to *like* it :-)

Answer (score 0):

put the body of the try{} block in another method:

```
  IndexSearch searcher = openSearcher();
  try {
    doSearch(searcher, query, resultWorker);
  } finally {
    searcher.close();
  }

private void doSearch(final IndexSearcher searcher, Query query, final ResultWorker resultWorker) {
  searcher.search(new HitCollector() {
    public void collect(int doc, float score) {
      resultWorker.add(new ProcessDocument(searcher.doc(doc));
    }
  });
}
```